# Can an organic compound have an ionic bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, ionic-compounds

Is there any organic compound that has another type of bond other than the covalent bond?

Comment: You see. The question is difficult to answer since the line that distinguishes organic compounds from inorganic ones isn't quite definite.

Answer (score 4):

There's a large number of salts with organic anions (e.g. *potassium hydrogen tartrate*) or organic cations (e.g. *tetrabutylammonium hexafluorophosphate*)

There are even salts, in which both the anion and the cation are organic compounds with covalent bonds. This is often used in pharmaceuticals. Here the active component appears in protonated form and is served as a salt with the conjugated bases of carboxyclic acids (e.g. *citrates*, *succinates*, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Of course, organic can make an ionic bond. For example: Acetylene

Acetylene is relatively acidic, even it's less acidic than water or alcohols. If acetylene reacts with strong base, it will form acetylide. For example: reaction between acetylene and sodium amide ($\ce {Na+ (NH2)-}$) will form sodium acetylide ($\ce {Na+ (H-C#C:)-}$). And this sodium acetylide is ionic and a organic compound.

Another compound is a organometallic compound like n-Butyllithium ($\ce{(CH3-CH2-CH2-CH2:)- Li+}$), Grignard reagents ($\ce{(R:)- (MgX)+}$), etc.

Comment: n-Butyllithium and Grignard reagents have polar covalent C-Mg and C-Li bonds

Answer (score 1):

React maleic anhydride with a mole of $\ce{H_2N-CH_2CH_2-N(CH_3)_3^+}$ to afford the zwitterionic amide.

Protein - with every kind of bonding interaction from the variety of amino acid side groups.  Hydrogen bonding, ionic bonding, covalent bonding, pi-stacking, zinc-fingers, charge transfer, etc.